# Default Browser Date Validation Suppressed with Jquery Validation

Tags: asp.net, jquery-validate, razor-pages, unobtrusive-validation

Our team is running into an issue with our date picker. We've a site we made with razor pages and bootstrap 5 and we have a form with a date picker. The date isn't a required field, so we have it as nullable. We're also using the jquery-validation and jquery-validation-unobtrusive which is what we've identified as causing the issue.

With the jquery-validation commented out, we are getting back the default browser pop-up, informing us that the date we entered was invalid (ie - 2/31/2023). When jquery-validation was re-enabled, this pop-up is getting suppressed. With the suppressed pop-up, the DateTime is returning a null value when passed an invalid date.

Ideally, we'd like to continue using the jquery-validation, but are wondering why this suppression is happening to begin with or if anyone else has run into this issue.

Comment: From what you describe everything is working as it should.  You either use jQuery Validate or you use HTML5 validation.  It's one or the other, not both.  The plugin leverages the `novalidate` attribute to turn off HTML5 validation.   I suggest you refer to the Microsoft documentation about how to properly implement the Unobtrusive plugin to achieve the desired validation.

Comment: With wide browser support for the `datetime-local` input, there really is no need to use third party date picker components these days: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms/dates-and-times